# Can't update the value of a state variable in Solidity!

Tags: solidity

In my contract there is a maaping of uint to an array of struct.

```
struct FactoryDetail{
 State itemState;            
 address factory;
 address warehouse;
 uint timeStamp1;
 uint timeStamp2;

}

mapping(uint=> FactoryDetail[]) public IdToFactory;
```

And a function to update the value of a factoryDetail based on uint key and index in the FactoryDetail array.

```
function factoryReceiveRawMaterials(uint256 _supplyChainId, address _warehouse) public{
    FactoryDetail[] memory fd =IdToFactory[_supplyChainId];
    for(uint i=0; i<fd.length; i++){
        if(fd[i].factory==msg.sender && fd[i].itemState== State.factoryBuyRawMaterial ){
            fd[i].warehouse =_warehouse;
            fd[i].itemState =State.factoryReceiveRawMaterials;
            fd[i].timeStamp1 =block.timestamp;
            temp=true;
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

But this is not working , when I am querying the value of IdToFactory, I'm seeing the old values.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is because you are using **memory** when you asign the value of your mapping to fd here:

```
FactoryDetail[] memory fd =IdToFactory[_supplyChainId];
```

that means that a copy of your value is created in memory and when you modify fd what is modified is that copy

If you need to modify the actual value you should use: **storage**

```
FactoryDetail[] storage fd =IdToFactory[_supplyChainId];
```

take a look at this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wOCIhzAuhgs) to learn more

you can read more about storage and memory [here](https://FactoryDetail%5B%5D%20memory%20fd%20=IdToFactory%5B_supplyChainId%5D;)

Answer (score 0):

You are making a `memory` copy of the storage array, which is fine, you just need to remember to update the storage array with the changes.

Making a copy of a storage array to then loop through it reading/updating values is a good idea because reading and writing from and to storage is really expensive in terms of gas. So, make a `memory` copy if you know you are going to read/write a lot to the array, but then remember to set the updated array to storage.

Add this line at the end of your `factoryReceiveRawMaterials` function:

```js
IdToFactory[_supplyChainId] = fd;
```

Like:

```js
function factoryReceiveRawMaterials(uint256 _supplyChainId, address _warehouse) public{
    FactoryDetail[] memory fd =IdToFactory[_supplyChainId];
    for(uint i=0; i<fd.length; i++){
        if(fd[i].factory==msg.sender && fd[i].itemState== State.factoryBuyRawMaterial ){
            fd[i].warehouse =_warehouse;
            fd[i].itemState =State.factoryReceiveRawMaterials;
            fd[i].timeStamp1 =block.timestamp;
            temp=true;
            return;
        }
    }
   IdToFactory[_supplyChainId] = fd;
}
```

This will update the storage array with the newly updated array.

You could also declare the `fd` variable as `storage`, but it would be probably more expensive to read/write to it multiple times. You can implement both and check the gas consumption for each approach.